# Ternary for clipShape swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to pick a clipShape based on a boolean value.

```
.clipShape(
        noText ? Circle() : Capsule()
)
```

this will not work because of this error:

```
Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Circle' and 'Capsule'
```

What is the best way to accomplish selecting a clip-shape based on a boolean value? Thanks

Comment: have you search for conditional modifier on SO? Or even searching on your error. There are probably hundreds of answers on this.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Typing this would take more time than searching for it, so I assure you, I am not just being lazy. I found nothing about what I asked, especially when it comes to shapes.

Comment: Have you tried a custom view modifier?

Comment: @cora no, can you please explain further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ? : expression need to ensure that both conditions are the same type, so to solve your problem just wrap your shape inside AnyShape(). Try below sample code(you can replace with your own image):

```
import SwiftUI

struct Practice: View {
@State private var test = false
var body: some View {
Image(systemName: "rectangle.fill")
    .resizable()
    .padding()
    .clipShape(test ? AnyShape(Circle()) : AnyShape(Capsule()))
    //For iOS 14 this can be done with .mask
    //.mask(test ? AnyView(Circle()) : AnyView(Capsule()))
Button("change shape") {
    test.toggle()
}
}

}
```

Comment: This would work, unfortunately I am using iOS 14, and this is for iOS 16. But thank you for responding.

Comment: If you are using iOS 14, I believe you can use mask. .mask(test ? AnyView(Circle()) : AnyView(Capsule())) since AnyView is available iOS 13+

Comment: Try and let me know.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for helping me here. These are the issues I get when I use mask
1- Type '(Mask) -> some View' cannot conform to 'Shape'
2- Generic parameter 'Mask' could not be inferred
3- Member 'mask' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'Shape.Protocol'; use a generic constraint instead

Comment: Interesting, i just tried that one again with iOS 14. It also worked. I guess it might be another problem either Xcode version or related view.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I used .mask inside of clipshape... lack of sleep does wonders. Thank you so much, you are a genius!

Comment: Enjoy. Happy coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246447/discussion-between-amin-and-tail).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution using custom modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var noText = false
    var body: some View {
        Image("example").resizable().myClipShape(noText: noText)
    }
}


struct myModifier: ViewModifier {
    var noText: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        VStack{
            if noText {
                content.clipShape(Circle())
            } else {
                content.clipShape(Capsule())
            }
        }
       
    }
}

extension View {
    func myClipShape(noText: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(myModifier(noText: noText))
    }
}
```

To create a custom modifier, first create a struct that conforms to `ViewModifier`. The `ViewModifier` protocol requires one thing which is the struct to have this method: `func body(content: Content) -> some View`. Inside the method, you can customize your custom modifier.

Then you can use your custom modifier like this:

```
Image("example").resizable().modifier(myModifier(noText: noText))
```

But if you're planning to use frequently, you can add it to the View Extension and use it like this too:

```
Image("example").resizable().myClipShape(noText: noText)
```